# How do I enlarge my gameobject(circle) in one straight go instead of enlarge it little by little (frame by frame) when hit the collision?

Tags: unity, c#

```
 public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    CircleAttack _Attack;
    [SerializeField] GameObject _circle;
    float getHit;
    float CircleTimer;

    public event System.Action OnPlayerDeath;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _Attack = _circle.GetComponent<CircleAttack>();
    }

    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Shards")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            getHit++;
            if (getHit >= 1)
            {
                _Attack.Expanding();
            }
        }
    }
```

This was a reference to this script of a gameobject that I want it to expand.I mean like gradually increases it continuously, not frame by frame. sorry I didn't phrase it properly

```
 public class CircleAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Expanding()
    {
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(2, 2, 2) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Comment: gradually increases it continuously means it grows frame by frame. Or do you mean instantly to the max size?

Comment: yes. Making it grow to the max size. But not in one shot, like see it's growing to that size

Comment: @Shihs Shihis,
Firstly you need to understand in which scenarios you would need Time.deltaTime. Currently I don't see this function being called in any update method this it won't give you the result that you need.

Comment: BTW, remove `if (getHit >= 1)`, it will be always true because just before calling it you increase the amount of it by one. other thing is that you may consider changing it to `int` as it store integer numbers only

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, what you want to do is this: call the function once, and then let it expand the object.

Well, that's a job for `coroutine`s as they won't run just in a frame. Here's what you should write instead:

```cs
public IEnumerator Expanding()
{
    while (transform.localScale != DesiredScale)
    {
        transform.localScale *= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

So basically what it does is this:

while the object's scale isn't the same as what you want it to be (`DesiredScale`) the coroutine will make it bigger by `Speed * Time.deltaTime` (the value of `Speed` depends on how fast you want the sphere to expand) and then waits until the next frame.

I suggest that you read more about `coroutine`s as they are, in my own experience, very useful and time-saving